# How do I disable multiple listboxes in one go using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, listbox

I can disable one and one by doing this:

```
jQuery('#ListBoxA').attr('disabled','true');
```

But how can I apply this to multiple items? This does not work:

```
jQuery('#ListBoxA, #ListBoxB, #ListBoxC').attr('disabled','true');
```

**UPDATE**

Not much markup to show....

```
<select id="ListBoxA" size="4" name="countrySelectBox">
<select id="ListBoxB" size="4" name="cityListBox">
<select id="ListBoxC" size="4" name="storeListBox" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: The second should work. And it should be: `.attr('disabled','disabled');`

Comment: Why `disabled` instead of `true` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`jQuery('#ListBoxA,#ListBoxB,#ListBoxC').attr('disabled','disabled');` (Without white spaces).

To enable use `jQuery('#ListBoxA,#ListBoxB,#ListBoxC').removeAttr('disabled');`

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/multiple#selector1selector2selectorN

Comment: Ah, thanks. It was the empty spaces. I got that from an example I found on the web.

Comment: Yeah, just discovered the removeAttr. Before that I used `.attr('disabled','');`

Answer (score 1):

For another option, if you give them all a CSS class, you can do:

```
jQuery('.ListBoxClass').attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Just like to add to this (correct) answer that it should technically be `attr('disabled', true)` (or `false`) as opposed to passing it the string `'true'`.

Comment: Correct. But I want to do this with ID's :)

Comment: Darin states above that I should use 'disabled' instead of 'true'. Anny comment on that?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use attribute filters if the boxes you want to disable share an attribute (in this case any one with 'ListBox' in it's id:

```
$("select[id*='ListBox']").attr('disabled',true);
```

Comment: Hmm... ok. What is the gain of doing attribute filtering?

Comment: @Steven, it could be of use if the selects are generated dynamically and you do not know how many there will be until runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the whitespace

For disabling items:

```
$("#ListBoxA,#ListBoxB,#ListBoxC").prop("disabled", true);
```

For enabling items:

```
$("#ListBoxA,#ListBoxB,#ListBoxC").prop("disabled", false);
```

Comment: Note; as of jQuery 1.6... to retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method [rather than the attr]. ref: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('select').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).attr('disabled','true');
});
```

Comment: This will not work, since I do not want to disable all listboxes on the page. Just a selected few.

Comment: If you put the ones you want in a container, then you can further update the selector appropriately using jQuery('#containerDiv select')